# Android - How to use Helmert Transformation to convert gps to screen XY on CUSTOM MAP

Tags: android, gps, customization

I have built an activity that takes a custom image that I use for a map and then knowing the gps at the top left and bottom right I plot a gps on top of the map. It works pretty good but I would like to get the accuracy up. I know its off because as I log the device location and plug it into the google map its actually more accurate than I am representing on my custom map.

So....being that I have the top left and bottom right gps of the map and have mapped them to the corresponding pixel coordinates how can I accurately plot the devices gps into pixels accurately using Helmert Transformation.

EDIT:

I am currently using this to plot the gps of the device to the screen.

```
public double getCurrentPixelY(Location upperLeft, Location lowerRight, Location current) {
    double hypotenuse = upperLeft.distanceTo(current);
    double bearing = upperLeft.bearingTo(current);
    double currentDistanceY = Math.cos(bearing * Math.PI / OneEightyDeg) * hypotenuse;
    //                           "percentage to mark the position"
    double totalHypotenuse = upperLeft.distanceTo(lowerRight);
    double totalDistanceY = totalHypotenuse * Math.cos(upperLeft.bearingTo(lowerRight) * Math.PI / OneEightyDeg);
    double currentPixelY = currentDistanceY / totalDistanceY * ImageSizeH;

    return currentPixelY;
}

public double getCurrentPixelX(Location upperLeft, Location lowerRight, Location current) {
    double hypotenuse = upperLeft.distanceTo(current);
    double bearing = upperLeft.bearingTo(current);
    double currentDistanceX = Math.sin(bearing * Math.PI / OneEightyDeg) * hypotenuse;
    //                           "percentage to mark the position"
    double totalHypotenuse = upperLeft.distanceTo(lowerRight);
    double totalDistanceX = totalHypotenuse * Math.sin(upperLeft.bearingTo(lowerRight) * Math.PI / OneEightyDeg);
    double currentPixelX = currentDistanceX / totalDistanceX * ImageSizeW;

    return currentPixelX;
}
```

I know I need to make an adjustment in there somewhere but looking at the helmert transformation I cant figure where to start implementing it with my existing code.

EDIT:

After looking at some more stuff online I can see that using the great circle formula might help. Heres a link to what Im looking at implementing

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/12types/GreatCircle.java.html

Comment: how many kilometers is the width of your image (aproximately)

Comment: The first one is 118.333 m  and the second is about 757.962 m

Comment: Those are the distances I get from using the distance tool on google maps

Comment: for such short distances the greater circle does not help. Fir the helmert you need 3 points.

Comment: When you say three points do you mean three corners? I already have the device gps, the top left gps, and the bottom right gps. Also what about using the Haverside formula?

Comment: the problem is not the curvature of the earth, it is the projection used in the picture.

Comment: Ok so being that I have three positions already how would I implement the helmert transformation with three gps coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is source code that calculates the helmert coefficients:

http://helmparms3d.sourceforge.net/

Maybe there is a simpler approach (there is also a so called 2d helmert transormation for small maps, like your picture)

Using that code you get the helmert coefficients, these coefficients is a 3x3 matrix. so you need code that is able to multiply a vector with a matrix.
The 3d graphic routines have such matrix multiplications.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think Im going to figure out how to use the 2d helmert transform. I guess I could use the 3d and ignore the z axis but I dont know what kind of results that would give me being that Im not to sure how i am going to implement the 2d version.

Comment: Hey Alex that link you gave me is to executables and not source code.

Comment: @Jamesandresakis look at the page, there is a src section for access the src via subversion (svn)

Comment: Oh I knew that I was just testing to see if you were paying attention :p Thanks :)

Comment: Thats really cool its in c I can just use JNI to keep it native :)